# Has this property for algebraic structures got a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, big-list

Given a binary operation $*:M\times M\rightarrow M$.
I define the extension of $*$ to the subset of $M$ in the usual way (with $A,B \subseteq M$)

$a*A:=\{a\}*A$and $A*a:=A*\{a\}$,

$$A*B:=\bigcup_{a\in A,b\in B}\{a*b\}$$

> $$
> \forall \, c \in M, \; \forall k \in \mathbb{N}
> \; : \; M \underbrace{* (M * (M * \cdots *(M *}_{k \text{ } *\text{s}}
> \{c\}))) \subset M * \{c\}
> $$

- Has this property got a name?
- Are there known non-commutative (and/or non-associative) algebraic structures with this property?

Comment: Non-commutatuve groups have this property, and I think as long as it's associative, any other structure will as well.

Comment: Not every property in mathematics must carry a name, only the most interesting ones. This one doesn't seem particularly deep.